# Best way to publish Large data from Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, performance, elasticsearch

We have Elastic DB which has employee task details, and we are publishing employee-wise tasks to Kafka every day using spring boot application.

Elastic DB index: employee_task

```
    {
    "employeeId":"E001",
    "taskName":"task1",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 11:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 16:00:00"
    }
    {
    "employeeId":"E001",
    "taskName":"task2",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 16:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 18:02:00"
    }
    {
    "employeeId":"E002",
    "taskName":"task3",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 09:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 18:00:00"
    }
```

Spring Boot Code:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.task.expression}")
    public void scheduleTasks() {
                //Get District Employee Ids from index employee_task
                List<String> employees = taskService.getAllEmployeeIds();   
                //fetch tasks from index employee_task for each employee and publish to Kafka      
                employees.parallelStream().forEach(employeeId -> {
                    Map<String, Object> tasksList = taskService.getAllTasksByEmployeeId(employeeId);
                    kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, mapper.writeValueAsString(tasksList));
                });
    }
```

It will publish task details to Kafka every day in the below format,

```
Message.1
{
"employeeId":"E001",
"taskList":[
    {
    "employeeId":"E001",
    "taskName":"task1",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 11:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 16:00:00"
    }
    {
    "employeeId":"E001",
    "taskName":"task2",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 16:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 18:02:00"
    }
]
}
Message.2
{
"employeeId":"E002",
"taskList":[
    {
    "employeeId":"E002",
    "taskName":"task3",
    "taskDesc":"task desc",
    "startDate":"2022-10-10 09:00:00",
    "endDate":"2022-10-10 18:00:00"
    }
]
}
```

Till now everything was working fine because the data was low. But now,

```
Current No. of employees: 10,000
Average Task per Employee: 100
```

So it's querying elastic DB 10K times when cron runs. Can anyone suggest what can be the best way to handle such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Old saying in the DB world of "row by row equals slow by slow". Given what is provided in the question I would guess the service calls the DB in some kind of loop. Some method needs to be written to obtain the data from the DB in one pass.